# How can I get my memory game to end when I have matched all pairs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, counter

I have almost all of the code done. My issue is that the counter I have implemented under the definition clicks() does not work. I have 16 items so when my equality of color comparison runs 8 times I want the function to stop. I cut a lot of the code that isn't relevant, the main focus is under the first if statement of clicks().

```
import graphics as G
import random

WINDOW_WIDTH = 200
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 200
win = G.GraphWin('Memory Game', WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)

def run_game():
    random_assignment()
    clicks()
        #if count == 8:
        #    game_running = False
        #if clicks() == True:
        #    count += 1
        #if count == 8:
        #    game_running = False
    #if game_running = False:


def clicks():
    game_running = True
    while game_running:
        first_click = win.getMouse()
        x_cell1 = int(first_click.getX()//50)
        y_cell1 = int(first_click.getY()//50)
        (first_r, first_c) = click_loc(first_click)
        first_r.undraw()
        second_click = win.getMouse()
        x_cell2 = int(second_click.getX()//50)
        y_cell2 = int(second_click.getY()//50)
        (second_r, second_c) = click_loc(second_click)
        second_r.undraw()
        rgb1 = circles[y_cell1][x_cell1]
        rgb2 = circles[y_cell2][x_cell2]
        count = 0
        if rgb1[0] == rgb2[0] and rgb1[1] == rgb2[1] and rgb1[2] == rgb2[2]:
            count += 1
        elif count == 8:
            game_running = False
        else:
            first_r.draw(win)
            second_r.draw(win)
    win.close()
def click_loc(click):
    x_cell = int(click.getX()//50)
    y_cell = int(click.getY()//50)
    (r, c) = board[x_cell][y_cell]
    return (r, c)


run_game()
```

Comment: I suspect this has something to do with you setting `count=0` inside the while loop => count will never reach 8?

Comment: try changing the "elif count == 8:" to "if count ==8"

Comment: Then why are you resetting the counter?

Answer (score 0):

To get the while loop working, you want to place the initialization of the counter (`count = 0`) outside the while loop.

Also, assuming you want to exit the loop once count reaches 8 you need to allow it to check the count (`if count >= 8`). Using `elif` means this will not be checked if the `if`-condition is `True`.

```
def clicks():
    game_running = True
    count = 0 # Initialize count before while loop
    while game_running:
        first_click = win.getMouse()
        x_cell1 = int(first_click.getX()//50)
        y_cell1 = int(first_click.getY()//50)
        (first_r, first_c) = click_loc(first_click)
        first_r.undraw()
        second_click = win.getMouse()
        x_cell2 = int(second_click.getX()//50)
        y_cell2 = int(second_click.getY()//50)
        (second_r, second_c) = click_loc(second_click)
        second_r.undraw()
        rgb1 = circles[y_cell1][x_cell1]
        rgb2 = circles[y_cell2][x_cell2]
        if rgb1[0] == rgb2[0] and rgb1[1] == rgb2[1] and rgb1[2] == rgb2[2]:
            count += 1
        if count >= 8: # use if instead of elif here 
            game_running = False
        else:
            first_r.draw(win)
            second_r.draw(win)
    win.close()
```

As a minor suggestion which should not matter in your case, but which I find to be more robust is to use "equal or greater than" `>=` instead of "equal to" `==`.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure count = 0 is not inside the while loop, because you're reseting it constantly while iterating.
Second, change the `elif count == 8` to `if count == 8` because when you use `elif`
it might   skip the `elif count == 8` when the count actually reaches 8 from the statement:

`if rgb1[0] == rgb2[0] and rgb1[1] == rgb2[1] and rgb1[2] == rgb2[2]:
    count += 1`

so replacing it with `if` makes sure that it will check the counter state.

the final code will look like:

```
def clicks():
count = 0
game_running = True
while game_running:
    first_click = win.getMouse()
    x_cell1 = int(first_click.getX()//50)
    y_cell1 = int(first_click.getY()//50)
    (first_r, first_c) = click_loc(first_click)
    first_r.undraw()
    second_click = win.getMouse()
    x_cell2 = int(second_click.getX()//50)
    y_cell2 = int(second_click.getY()//50)
    (second_r, second_c) = click_loc(second_click)
    second_r.undraw()
    rgb1 = circles[y_cell1][x_cell1]
    rgb2 = circles[y_cell2][x_cell2]
    if rgb1[0] == rgb2[0] and rgb1[1] == rgb2[1] and rgb1[2] == rgb2[2]:
        count += 1
    if count == 8: 
        game_running = False
    else:
        first_r.draw(win)
        second_r.draw(win)
win.close()
```